# Android database based app - OOP approach, garbage collection questions

Tags: android, oop, object, garbage-collection

I was doing my 1st steps with android writing a money manager. It stores data in SQLite database and my approach was mostly procedural, while I was creating it.

It means: when I'm creating a chart or a summary it's look like this:

1. I create a database cursor
2. I iterate over that cursor to collect neccessary data
3. I pass the data directly to the element I need (a chart or listview for example)

**Well, that works, but I'm learning more oop now and I'd like to rebuild my app. 
I'm not fully aware of memory restrictions on mobile devices, that's why I'm creating this thread.**

**I came up with two ideas. Please tell me, which one you think is better** (or correct my approach somehow if it's completly wrong).

Lets use an example of creating a chart or a listview like before. Now I'd do this that way:

1. I create database cursor.
2. I create number of objects equal to number of records I need to present data.
3. I use created objects to pass the data to chart or a listview.

This will require more code than my procedural approach but use of it should be much simplier then, and the code would has more 'proffessional' look **(correct me if I'm wrong)**.

However, I got this dilema. Let's say I'm creating a set of objects based on data from table 'expenses'. I use them to present a chart or a listview on one of my activity. After I close the activity I don't need them anymore. **What should I do to let garbage collector toss them away. Anything particullar?** (yes, I'm new to the garbage collector stuff).

There is also second oop approach but I'm aware it will require a lot of memory and I'm not sure if it's a good idea at all. So, back to the example again:

1. I create cursors for each table I got
2. I create a set of objects matching the tables - basically I pass all the tables into set of objects for further use (I do it in a thread with some progress bar if necessary)
3. I use the created objects anytime I need to present my data.

Sounds silly, huh? **I'm not sure when the garbage collector would dispose all those objects, and if it's a good idea to spam memory with that amount of data in once.**

Thanks for any comments on this.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions work, but the first one is better because the objects are marked for GC as soon as they go out of scope, which happens much earlier than if they are kept for later use. Once the objects are GCed, the memory they occupied becomes available.